# Using InputMismatchException try/catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

I want to catch any input that is not an Int and prompt for a valid input 3 times.  After 3 times, the program will move on and ask for another rating.  I can't seem to have the try/catch block repeat or even catch the InputMismatchException. Any suggestions?

```
do {
    //prompt for rating
        try {
        System.out.println("Enter a rating between 0-4 for the Movie of the Week (Enter -1 to stop/exit): ");
        //capture
            rating = response.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException err) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a rating 0-4 or enter -1 to exit: ");
            rating = response.nextInt();
        } //end catch
    } while (rating >= 0);
```

Comment: Add a `counter` of some kind outside of the `do-while` loop, intiialised to `0`, in the `catch` block, increment the `counter` and set the `rating` to `-2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could either do it in a loop:

```
int count = 0;
do {
    //prompt for rating
        try {
        System.out.println("Enter a rating between 0-4 for the Movie of the Week (Enter -1 to stop/exit): ");
        //capture
            rating = response.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException err) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a rating 0-4 or enter -1 to exit: ");
            count++;
        } //end catch
    } while (rating >= 0 && count < 3);
```

Or use a nested try/ catch:

```
do {
    //prompt for rating
        try {
        System.out.println("Enter a rating between 0-4 for the Movie of the Week (Enter -1 to stop/exit): ");
        //capture
            rating = response.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException err) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a rating 0-4 or enter -1 to exit: ");
             try {
        System.out.println("Enter a rating between 0-4 for the Movie of the Week (Enter -1 to stop/exit): ");
        //capture
            rating = response.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException err) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a rating 0-4 or enter -1 to exit: ");
            rating = response.nextInt();
        } //end catch
        } //end catch
    } while (rating >= 0);
```

Personally I would prefer the first method.

I tried this code and it ran without any Exception:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    int rating = 0;
    do {
        Scanner response = new Scanner(System.in);
        //prompt for rating
            try {
            System.out.println("Enter a rating between 0-4 for the Movie of the Week (Enter -1 to stop/exit): ");
            //capture
                rating = response.nextInt();

            } catch (InputMismatchException err) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a rating 0-4 or enter -1 to exit: ");
            } finally {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Rating-->" + rating);
            }
      } while (rating >= 0 && count < 3);

}
```

}

Comment: My program still throws an InputMismatchException error even though I catch it and prompt for another rating. Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: I did end up using the first suggestion though for prompting for it 3 times.

Comment: I just tried a piece of code and it ran without any exception.